# Do aircraft engines come with electric generators?

Tags: turbofan, turboprop, aircraft-manufacturer, turbojet, engine-manufacturing

For turbojet/fan/prop engines, do they come with an electric generator when delivered to aircraft manufacturers, or it is something that the aircraft manufacturer has to find or make themselves?

I am especially interested in whether GE H-series H85-100 and H85-200 engines come with electric generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For turbofan engines, there is usually a very small generator included that powers the engine controls.  If the aircraft manufacturers wants a big generator to power the aircraft (and they pretty much always do), that is furnished by the aircraft manufacturer.  They generally do not make it themselves, they buy it.

I do not know for turboprops.

Comment: The two engines cited in the question have no FADEC/EEC so I guess this generator is not present either, EEC is an option it seems. Or is this generator also used for igniters?